# How do you find something in a dictionary without knowing the name of the dictionary

Tags: swift, ipad, swift-playground

I’m using Swift playgrounds the “Anwsers Template”
Let’s say I have:

Let apple = [“cost”: 10, “nutrition”: 5]
Let banana = [“cost”: 15, “nutrition”: 10]

Let choice = askForChoice(Options:[“Apple”, “Banana”])

What is a good, easy way of finding the cost of each fruit, without using a “if” function, because I may make over 100 different things.

Comment: Please copy and paste real code and please format it correctly.

Comment: why don't make a class for fruits (with parameters cost and nutrition) and then make a dictionary of fruits?
e.g. make subclasses for apple, banana,..

Comment: @rmaddy why do you need the real code?

Comment: Please include code that you have tried so far. SO is not a code writing service. You should make some effort and then ask when you have a particular problem.

Comment: I don’t usually include the entire code because it is very long, and if someone has the promblem they may not understand the answer because it will not apply to their project. But I will include the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// A good, more object oriented way-

struct Fruit{

    var name: String
    var cost: Double
    var nutrition: Int
}


let fruitsDataHolder = [
    Fruit(name: "Apple", cost: 10.0, nutrition: 5),
    Fruit(name: "Banana", cost: 15.0, nutrition: 10)
]

func getFruitsCost(fruits: [Fruit]) -> Double{

    var totalCost = 0.0
    for fruit in fruits{ totalCost += fruit.cost }

    return totalCost
}


print(getFruitsCost(fruits: fruitsDataHolder)) // prints 25.0
```

If you insist on doing that with dictionaries:

```
let fruitsDataHolder2 = [
    ["name": "Apple", "cost": 10.0, "nutrition": 5],
    ["name": "Banana", "cost": 15.0, "nutrition": 10]
]

func getFruitsCost2(fruits: [[String: Any]]) -> Double{

    var totalCost = 0.0

    for fruit in fruits{
        let cost = fruit["cost"] as! Double
        totalCost += cost
    }

    return totalCost
}

print(getFruitsCost2(fruits: fruitsDataHolder2)) // prints 25.0
```

**Edit**
Here's how you can get a specific fruit's cost based on his name

For the first way-

```
func getFruitCost(fruitName: String, fruits: [Fruit]) -> Double?{

    // searching for the fruit
    for fruit in fruits{

        if fruit.name == fruitName{
            // found the fruit, returning his cost
            return fruit.cost
        }
    }
    // couldn't find that fruit
    return nil
}
```

For the second way-

```
func getFruitCost2(fruitName: String, fruits: [[String: Any]]) -> Double?{

    // searching for the fruit
    for fruit in fruits{
        let currentFruitName = fruit["name"] as! String

        if currentFruitName == fruitName{
            // found the fruit, returning his cost

            return fruit["cost"] as! Double
        }
    }

    // couldn't find that fruit
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Does it work if I only want the user to only give the name of the fruit, instead of all of the fruit information.

Comment: Just edited- here's how you can get a fruit's cost with his name

Comment: Is it possible to add new fruits into “newFruitDataHolder”, through user input?

Comment: Yes, it’s possible. You can read/watch some tutorials on the web, I’m not covering it